# CSS Transition and Transform Not Working in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: css, safari, transform, transition

I am having a problem getting a underline bar to animate under a text link. You can see a working example here: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/

The animation works fine in all browsers except for Safari 5.1.7. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code snippet:

EDIT: Sorry about that, I added the html and more of the CSS rules. I hope that helps.

```css
.infiniteNav{
 width: 100%;
 height: 56px;
 background-color: #9e0707;
 background: linear-gradient(#c71e1e, #800909);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c71e1e, #800909);
 position: absolute;
 top: 271px;
 z-index: -2;
}

nav{
 width: 955px;
 height: 56px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 background-color: #9e0707;
 background: linear-gradient( #c71e1e, #800909);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c71e1e, #800909);
}

nav a{
 position: relative;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: arial;
 color: #e0e0e0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0px 15px;
 line-height: 55px;
}

/********************************************************************************************************
This is the animated underline bar.                  *
********************************************************************************************************/

nav a:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
 transform: scaleX(0);
 /*-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;*/
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav a:hover:before{
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
 color: #e0e0e0;
}

nav a:active{
 color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="sales.html">Sales</a>
    <a href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>
    <a href="events.html">Events</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
    <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML to your code snippet!